# Keeping notification from dismissing when service is destroyed in Oreo

Tags: android, service, notifications, media-player

Okay. I had a question regaurding keeping Media Player Services in Android Oreo. Based on the discussion here:

[Android Oreo: Keep started background service alive without setting it foreground (but with a notification)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48178194/android-oreo-keep-started-background-service-alive-without-setting-it-foregroun)

It seems the proper way to handle Media player services in Android Oreo is to store state information when the media player is paused so if it is destroyed, pressing play will create a new media player and start where it left off.

My question is how do I create a notification that won't get destroyed when the service that started it is destroyed. I am not running any code to dismiss the notification but it is still being dismissed automatically when the service is destoryed. As you can see in my code, I can rebuild the notification onDestroy, but I don't like the way this looks as the user can see it dismissing and rebuilding again.

Here is my notification code:

```
private void buildNotification() {
        Cat.d("building notification");
        final MediaPlayerService context = this;

        RequestBuilder<Bitmap> requestBuilder = Glide.with(this).asBitmap()
                .load(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        NotificationCompat.Action action;
        if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            action = generateAction(R.drawable.ic_pause, "Pause");
        else
            action = generateAction(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow, "Play");

        int[] actionsInCompact;

        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_navbooks_icon_black)
                //.setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setContentTitle(book.getTitle())
                .setContentText(book.getAuthor())
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setContentIntent(PendingIntentHelper.getOpenMainActivityIntent(context, book.getId()))
                .setDeleteIntent(PendingIntentHelper.getStopServiceIntent(context));

        if (SettingsUtil.GetNotificationSkip(context)) {
            builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_skip_backward, "Skip Previous",
                    PendingIntentHelper.getSkipBackwardIntent(context))
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_backward, "Rewind",
                            PendingIntentHelper.getSeekBackwardIntent(context))
                    .addAction(action)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_forward, "Fast Forward",
                            PendingIntentHelper.getSeekForwardIntent(context))
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_skip_forward, "Skip Next",
                            PendingIntentHelper.getSkipForwardIntent(context));
            actionsInCompact = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
        } else {
            builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_backward, "Rewind",
                    PendingIntentHelper.getSeekBackwardIntent(context))
                    .addAction(action)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_forward, "Fast Forward",
                            PendingIntentHelper.getSeekForwardIntent(context));
            actionsInCompact = new int[]{0, 1, 2};
        }
        builder.setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                .setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken())
                .setShowActionsInCompactView(actionsInCompact));

        // Load a cover image if there isn't one loaded yet or the cover has changed
        if(cover == null || !book.getCover().equals(lastCover)) {
            lastCover = book.getCover();
            mediaSession.setMetadata(new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                    .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, book.getTitle())
                    .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, book.getAuthor())
                    .build());
            Glide.with(this)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .error(requestBuilder)
                    .load(book.getCover())
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap largeIcon, Transition transition) {
                            Cat.d("Finished loading");
                            cover = largeIcon;
                            // initBuilder
                            builder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);
                            mediaSession.setMetadata(new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                                    .putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, largeIcon)
                                    .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, book.getTitle())
                                    .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, book.getAuthor())
                                    .build());
                            startNotification();
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            mediaSession.setMetadata(new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                    .putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, cover)
                    .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, book.getTitle())
                    .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, book.getAuthor())
                    .build());
            if(cover != null)
                builder.setLargeIcon(cover);
        }

        startNotification();
    }

    private NotificationCompat.Action generateAction(int icon, String title) {
        return new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder( icon, title, PendingIntentHelper.getPlayPauseIntent(this)).build();
    }

    private void startNotification() {
        mediaSession.setPlaybackState(new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                .setActions(MEDIA_SESSION_ACTIONS)
                .setState(mediaPlayer.isPlaying() ? PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING :
                        PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED, book.getLastPosition(), 1)
                .build());

        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
        else
        {
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            if(notificationManager != null) {
                notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
            }
            stopForeground(false);
        }
    }
```

And here is what happens when the service is destroyed:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    //super.onDestroy();
    handleDestroy();
}

private void handleDestroy() {
        if(book != null)
            sendProgressUpdate();
        else
            book = new BookDBHelper(this).getBook(SettingsUtil.GetLastPlayedBook(this));
        if(mediaPlayer != null) {
            book.setLastPosition(this, getPosition());
            SyncHelper.SendProgressUpdate(this, book);
        }
        if(mediaSession != null)
            mediaSession.release();

        if(noisyRegistered) {
            unregisterReceiver(becomingNoisyReceiver);
            unregisterReceiver(shakeReceiver);
        }
        buildNotification();
    }
```

Comment: "My question is how do I create a notification that won't get destroyed when the service that started it is destroyed" -- if the service is destroyed, what value does the `Notification` have for the user?

Comment: Android 8 will destroy any service not running in the foreground after a certain amount of time. If I can keep the notification from being dismissed, the user can start the media player again picking up where they left off from the notification without having to open the app.

Comment: "Android 8 will destroy any service not running in the foreground after a certain amount of time" -- your service should be running only while it is playing. Once the user pauses playback, you stop the service, until such time as the user elects to resume playback. [Only have a service running when it is actively delivering value to the user](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/27/role-services.html). In terms of your feature, please make that opt-in, and AFAIK you will have to re-raise the `Notification` as part of stopping the service.

Comment: I'm not trying to prevent the service from being destroyed and understand that a service shouldn't be running if it is not doing anything. I'm trying to figure out why the notification is being dismissed. To test, I had the service start another notification and it didn't get dismissed when the service was destoryed `NotificationCompat.Builder(this.getApplicationContext(), NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_navbooks_icon_black)
                    .setContentTitle(book.getTitle())
            notificationManager.notify(24678, testNotification.build());`

Comment: @JoelPage please let me know if you get any solution regarding to dismiss notification in >= oreo. thanks.

Comment: @TusharLathiya See my solution below.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Okay. I found out that the stopForeground function has an optional parameter of a flag instead of a boolean. It can be given a flag STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH which is necessary to detach the notification from the service even after calling stopForeground so that when the service is destroyed, the notification won't be dismissed and a new notification doesn't have to be built. Here is my updated code for starting the notification:

```
private fun updateNotification(preparing: Boolean = false) {
    if(getPlaying()) { 
        startService(Intent(applicationContext, this@MediaPlayerService.javaClass))
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification())
    }else {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            stopForeground(Service.STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH)
        else
            stopForeground(false)
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification())
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good point! Nevertheless this works for API 24 and above. What About API 23 and lower? it seems stopForeground(false) doesn't keep notification...

Comment: I've updated my sample function with the code I currently use. A couple of things I added: startService before startForeground fixes the notification being dismissed when the activity that starts it is closed. Also call notify after stopForeground(false) to update and keep a background notification.

Comment: Thx. for quick response Joel. There seems to be one thing not precisely written. And that is the `startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification())` which is available since Build.VERSION_CODES.O

Comment: I don't understand the problem. This code runs fine on my app which has a minimum SDK of 21.

Comment: Ah, sorry. You'r right. Not sure now why I wrote that last note. stgartForeground seems to be ready as you said.